# mostrar campo de una consulta php con PDO

Tags: php

Estoy intentando intentando imprimir un usuario que se cuentra registrado en mi base de datos como prueba para implementarlo en angunos datos mas adelante, tengo una base de datos con una tabla de usuarios
en donde despues de llenar un formulario (usuario y contraceña) se envian a la misma pag ***php_self*** para lo que utilizo este condicional e imprimir dicho usuario (ingresado en el form) ya comparado en la db, pero no me arroja el resultado, ya probe con return y con esta manera

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $usuariodb = $_POST['usuario'];

    $conexion_usr = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ws_blog;charset=UTF8','root','');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_blog WHERE name ='".strtolower($usuariodb)."'";
    $result = $conexion_usr->query($sql);
    $usr_name = $result->fetchAll();
    foreach ($usr_name as $names) {
        echo $names;
    }

}
```

y esta otra

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $usuariodb = $_POST['usuario'];

    $conexion_usr = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ws_blog;charset=UTF8','root','');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_blog WHERE name ='".strtolower($usuariodb)."'";
    $result = $conexion_usr->query($sql);
    return $result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución que encontré a mi problema:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $usuariodb = $_POST['usuario'];

    $conexion_usr = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ws_blog;charset=UTF8','root','');
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM user_blog WHERE name ='".strtolower($usuariodb)."'";
    $result = $conexion_usr->query($sql);
    $usr_name = $result->fetchColumn();
    }
```

Comment: Esta consulta permite ataques de injection SQL, deberia ser preparada previamente.